# How to view and browse windows shared folders in entire local network?

Tags: networking, windows, samba, smb, shared-folders

So as the title suggest, I'm looking for a way to display all shared folders on all shared machines in a local MS Windows network.

I can list shares on a known windows machine with:

```
smbclient -L //SERVER -U username
```

This shows me a list of shares on that server, and I can then connect to those via mounting `cifs`, or simply connecting to the shares through Thunar.

But I cannot list *all* machines in the network sharing folders like this.

I have a "Windows Network" icon in Thunar, but that only lists my own share which I have configured with `samba`. On MS Windows, it is possible to see all "nearby" machines offering shared folders, I can easily browse them, etc.

Since I can list shares with `smbclient`, using that would be the icing on the cake, but I need a way to list all available Windows computers in a network whichever way. Graphical or command line, both are fine, I'd actually prefer if I can have a solution both ways.

I tried `nmblookup` but this does list only a few machines on the network I don't have access to. The machines with the shares I need, don't show up at all.

Also, `smbtree` shows up nothing, but the Windows shares are visible to all other Windows users.

Also, `avahi-browse -a` also doesn't return anything besides the shares already visible in Thunar, which is far from all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a terminal based solution, you can use

```
nmblookup -S '*'
```

which shows all Samba shares in your broadcast domain.

More can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/166255/124472).

Comment: Hmm, ok. Next time I'll in that network, I'll try.

Comment: It's not entirely what I was looking for, but it put me onto the right track. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

I use Manjaro 18 with xfce and Thunar File manager.

I found that manually typing:

```
smb://SERVER_IP/...
```

into the path bar of the file manager window finally mounted the shared network in the sidebar of the window.

(running `~$ <name_of_file_manager> smb://SERVER_IP` in a terminal will also work)

[image: Thunar path bar]
[image: Shared network folder mounted]

Comment: This was super helpful than you!